# Dial a number on smartphone app

Tags: android, ios, smartphone

We are currently prototyping an application that will have a version for android and iPhone systems. On a user interaction, The app is supposed to start a phone call to a phone number, but because of internal security reasons the user is not supposed to see the phone number. I am aware of the fact that it is possible to tell the OS which number to call, but is it possible to hide the number from the user?

Comment: I really hope that it isn't...

Comment: "Your phone is now calling a random number."

Comment: I do not believe that this is possible with iOS or Android.

Answer (score 0):

No.
I'm curious though, why would you want to do that?

A possible solution (depending on the 'why') is: have the device connect to a webserver over http telling the server what the phone number is. Then make that webserver call the phone from a 'hidden' number. The webserver has to be connected to some dialing machine obviously.

Comment: I know how dangerous for malware something like this would be. The thing is that the user  is supossed to be talking to the person on the other side.

Comment: If i would have something like that as a service, we would have to make a SIP application and force the user to make a VPN connectio to our network in order to be able to vonnect to our asterisk server and to be authenticated as an extension. Something like that is out of the question. Too many security threats for our servers and also it would kill our budget since the SIP trunk's costs would go through the roof.